# Would [NSData writeToFile: atomically] throw an exception when error happens?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am trying to invoke [NSData writeToFile: atomically] in multithread.

```
[myLock lock];
[myData writeToFile:aPath atomically:YES];
[myLock unlock];
```

But if writeToFile throw an exception, the [myLock unlock] will not be called. So, should I use try-cache like this?

```
@try
{
    [myLock lock];
    [myData writeToFile:aPath atomically:YES];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    // deal with the exception
}
@finally {
    [myLock unlock];
}
```

**Update:**
change 'automatically'  to  'atomically'

Comment: It should be [myData writeToFile:aPath atomically:YES]; not automatically

Comment: Thanks. It is a typo.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It will not throw any exception (also no where in the documentation says that too). If you are concerned about dealing with error, use the other API:

```
- writeToFile:options:error:
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the method is

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString * nonnull)path
     atomically:(BOOL)atomically
```

not **automatically**, probably just a typo.

Second, writeToFile will not raise an exception, it will simply return a BOOL, indicating whether the writing failed or succeeded.

```
[myLock unlock];
```

Will  be called anyway and you don't need to catch any exception.

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:)

Comment: The documentation does not mention that writeToFile method will or will not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`@finally` is called regardless if an exception was catched or not so you don't need to worry about it not being unlocked.